# How do you run behave (with python code) steps implementation with gherkin scenarios data input?

Tags: python-behave

I start python and TDD, I would like to know how to run behave steps with python and scenarios table for the two scenarios below:

The program ask a user to enter data  (humididity level and temperature) and it prints those data.

- **For the first scenario**, user fill out data and the program prints those data (normal case). I just want to check if there is data input
- **For the second scenario**, if user fill out "text" the program return a syntax error.I would like to check the data type in @then steps

The problem is that when I run steps with *behave* command it asks me to enter data but I want the program uses data table in gherkin scenarios. Can you help please?

gherkin scenario below:

```
Feature: As a user I want fill out humidex data to visualize it

 Scenario: user fill out humidex data correctly
    Given a user
    When user fill out humidexdata
      |humidity|temperature|
      |50%     |28C°       |
    Then user visualize
      |humidity|temperature|
      |50%     |28C°       |

 Scenario: user fill out humidex data with text
    Given a user
    When user fill out humidexdata
      |humidity   |temperature|
      |lorem ipsum|lorem ipsum|
    Then user visualize a syntax error "data syntax is wrong retry"
```

step implementations with behave:

```
from behave import *
from fillouthumidexdata import *

@given(u'a user')
def step_impl(context):
    context.user = User()

@when(u'user fill out humidexdata')
def step_impl(context):
    context.user.fillout_humidexData()


@then(u'user visualize')
def step_impl(context):
    context.user.visualize_humidexData()
```

python code:

```
class User():

    def __init__(self):
        self.humidity = []
        self.temperature =[]

    def fillout_humidexData(self):

        print("Enter humidity level (%)")
        input(self.humidity)
        print("Enter temperature (C°)")
        input(self.temperature)

    def visualize_humidexData(self):
        print(self.humidity)
        print(self.temperature)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need actually separate User class as all of that can be done in simple steps, but following this approach I would change first a bit the User class at least to:

```
class User():

def __init__(self):
    self.humidity = 0
    self.temperature = 0

def fillout_humidexData(self, humidity, temperature):
    self.humidity = humidity
    self.temperature = temperature

def visualize_humidexData(self):
    print(f'humidity: {self.humidity}')
    print(f'temperature: {self.temperature}')
```

And then use the following steps:

```
from behave import step, given, when, then
from fillouthumidexdata import *


@given(u'a user')
def step_impl(context):
    context.user = User()


@when(u'user fill out humidexdata')
def step_impl(context):
    humidity, temperature = context.table.rows[0]
    context.user.fillout_humidexData(humidity, temperature)


@then(u'user visualize')
def step_impl(context):
    context.user.visualize_humidexData()
```

rows[0] should give you values from first row in your setup table(2 values from 2 columns).
I think this should work, but I am not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: Hello Krysztof, Thank you for your answer. It works perfectly. I would like to check in when step if "humidity" and "temperature" are number and not string with parse_number arguments. I tried but failed

Comment: And I have another question about in my little program step_impl are reading gherkin table. the program is running with table data. What about the case when a user fill out a data or wrong data ? how do you change the source of your data to check the real behaviour of your program.  (I'm starting with bdd tdd, maybe it's a nerd question, sorry for that)

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Real behavior you can check by connection to your real program or app. Usually there is some UI or API available. Otherwise it's kind of unit testing.